why qr not read quickly until i make zoom to qr to read?
I make code to read qr code but I face issue it read qr code with difficult way
I must make qr big zoom for qr and more close from qr to read it success
so how to handle that
what features I must add or reduce from qr to handle it quickly .
I Need any way can mae qr code read quickly
what I can enhance it to make performance very quickly
 public static string RenderQrCodeNewTruckerLogo(string P_ENC_Text, Color color, string GovName)
    {
        string ImageName = "NewTruckerLogo.png";
        
        string level = "L";//comboBoxECC.SelectedItem.ToString();
        QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel eccLevel = (QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel)(level == "L" ? 0 : level == "M" ? 1 : level == "Q" ? 2 : 3);
        using (QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator())
        {
            using (QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(P_ENC_Text, eccLevel))
            {
                using (QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData))
                {
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    //Bitmap bitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20, color, Color.White,
                    //    null, 15);
                    Bitmap bitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(30, color, Color.White,
                        null, 15);
                    var LogoFilePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/assets/images/"), ImageName);
                    //var logoImg = Image.FromFile(LogoFilePath);
                    Bitmap logo = new Bitmap(LogoFilePath);
                    logo = Common.ResizeBitmap(logo, 300, 300);
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
                    g.DrawImage(logo, new Point((bitmap.Width - logo.Width) / 2, (bitmap.Height - logo.Height) / 2));
                    bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                    var base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                
                    string Src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64Data;
                    return Src;

                }
            }
        }
    }
  public QRCodeData CreateQrCode(string plainText, ECCLevel eccLevel, bool forceUtf8 = false, bool utf8BOM = false, EciMode eciMode = EciMode.Default, int requestedVersion = -1)
        {
            return GenerateQrCode(plainText, eccLevel, forceUtf8, utf8BOM, eciMode, requestedVersion);
        }
 public static QRCodeData GenerateQrCode(string plainText, ECCLevel eccLevel, bool forceUtf8 = false, bool utf8BOM = false, EciMode eciMode = EciMode.Default, int requestedVersion = -1)
        {
            EncodingMode encoding = GetEncodingFromPlaintext(plainText, forceUtf8);
            var codedText = PlainTextToBinary(plainText, encoding, eciMode, utf8BOM, forceUtf8);
            var dataInputLength = GetDataLength(encoding, plainText, codedText, forceUtf8);
            int version = requestedVersion;
            if (version == -1)
            {
                version = GetVersion(dataInputLength, encoding, eccLevel);
            }

            string modeIndicator = String.Empty;
            if (eciMode != EciMode.Default)
            {
                modeIndicator = DecToBin((int)EncodingMode.ECI, 4);
                modeIndicator += DecToBin((int)eciMode, 8);
            }
            modeIndicator += DecToBin((int)encoding, 4);
            var countIndicator = DecToBin(dataInputLength, GetCountIndicatorLength(version, encoding));
            var bitString = modeIndicator + countIndicator;

            bitString += codedText;

            return GenerateQrCode(bitString, eccLevel, version);
        }
    public static Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int width, int height)
    {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, width, height);
        }

        return result;
    }
        public Bitmap GetGraphic(int pixelsPerModule, Color darkColor, Color lightColor, Bitmap icon=null, int iconSizePercent=15, int iconBorderWidth = 6, bool drawQuietZones = true)
        {
            var size = (this.QrCodeData.ModuleMatrix.Count - (drawQuietZones ? 0 : 8)) * pixelsPerModule;
            var offset = drawQuietZones ? 0 : 4 * pixelsPerModule;

            var bmp = new Bitmap(size, size, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            using (var lightBrush = new SolidBrush(lightColor))
            using (var darkBrush = new SolidBrush(darkColor))
            {
                gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gfx.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                gfx.Clear(lightColor);

                var drawIconFlag = icon != null && iconSizePercent > 0 && iconSizePercent <= 100;

                GraphicsPath iconPath = null;
                float iconDestWidth = 0, iconDestHeight = 0, iconX = 0, iconY = 0;

                if (drawIconFlag)
                {
                    iconDestWidth = iconSizePercent * bmp.Width / 100f;
                    iconDestHeight = drawIconFlag ? iconDestWidth * icon.Height / icon.Width : 0;
                    iconX = (bmp.Width - iconDestWidth) / 2;
                    iconY = (bmp.Height - iconDestHeight) / 2;

                    var centerDest = new RectangleF(iconX - iconBorderWidth, iconY - iconBorderWidth, iconDestWidth + iconBorderWidth * 2, iconDestHeight + iconBorderWidth * 2);
                    iconPath = this.CreateRoundedRectanglePath(centerDest, iconBorderWidth * 2);
                }

                for (var x = 0; x < size + offset; x = x + pixelsPerModule)
                {
                    for (var y = 0; y < size + offset; y = y + pixelsPerModule)
                    {
                        var module = this.QrCodeData.ModuleMatrix[(y + pixelsPerModule) / pixelsPerModule - 1][(x + pixelsPerModule) / pixelsPerModule - 1];

                        if (module)
                        {
                            var r = new Rectangle(x - offset, y - offset, pixelsPerModule, pixelsPerModule);

                            if (drawIconFlag)
                            {
                                var region = new Region(r);
                                region.Exclude(iconPath);
                                gfx.FillRegion(darkBrush, region);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                gfx.FillRectangle(darkBrush, r);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            gfx.FillRectangle(lightBrush, new Rectangle(x - offset, y - offset, pixelsPerModule, pixelsPerModule));
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (drawIconFlag)
                {
                    var iconDestRect = new RectangleF(iconX, iconY, iconDestWidth, iconDestHeight);
                    gfx.DrawImage(icon, iconDestRect, new RectangleF(0, 0, icon.Width, icon.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }

                gfx.Save();
            }

            return bmp;
    

}


public static string RenderQrCodeNewTruckerLogo(string P_ENC_Text, Color color, string GovName)
{
    string ImageName = "NewTruckerLogo.png";
    
    string level = "L";//comboBoxECC.SelectedItem.ToString();
    QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel eccLevel = (QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel)(level == "L" ? 0 : level == "M" ? 1 : level == "Q" ? 2 : 3);
    using (QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator())
    {
        using (QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(P_ENC_Text, eccLevel))
        {
            using (QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData))
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                //Bitmap bitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20, color, Color.White,
                //    null, 15);
                Bitmap bitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(30, color, Color.White,
                    null, 15);
                var LogoFilePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/assets/images/"), ImageName);
                //var logoImg = Image.FromFile(LogoFilePath);
                Bitmap logo = new Bitmap(LogoFilePath);

sis that mdi me

Perhaps a comment saying what this does?

thank you so what changes on code posted

can any one help me on that

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
